# Bash script wait depended commands processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I am fairly new in bash scripting. I need to use bash script for manage my microservices, so these services need build and deploy(on docker).

So I have commands like that :

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn clean
wait $!
mvn package
wait $!
#Some if elses here
sudo docker build -t myService . &
wait $!
#Some if elses here
sudo -S docker run -d -name myService myService &
```

So as you see(a little part of script, i am grouping depended commands  in functions),commands need to wait previous depended commands like that. But `wait $!` command doesn't look nice after all command.

Are there any approaches for this situations?(I am open other approaches instead of bash scripting if it is handy solution. Btw services are node and java services seperated, so I need to start all of them with one bash script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically wait for a command, just don't add a `&` to them:

```
sudo docker build -t myService .
sudo -S docker run -d -name myService myService
```

This waits for `sudo docker build -t myService .` to completely exit before continuing with `sudo -S docker run -d -name myService myService`. It then waits for `sudo -S docker run -d -name myService myService` to completely exit before continuing with anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's okay for maven commands but for docker build and run commands it needs wait, I just wonder do I have to use wait $! for depended processes per line.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut I updated the example to use the `docker` commands instead of the `mvn` commands. They work exactly the same way, but hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: Btw I am using `&` notation for some background server jobs is it correct for background situations?, so in docker commands its my bad. Also I couldn't realize `wait $!` when need it exactly?

Comment: You only need it if you want to parallellize commands for efficiency. For example, you can do `gzip backup_alice.tar & gzip backup_bob.tar; wait $!; scp backup_*.tar.gz host:/backups` to compress two files at the same time on a multicore system

Comment: Thanks for clarification.